# RegExp to match date and time from custom log file

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I am writing a script that in order to achieve greatness have to convert a date and time format from a log file to a timestamp. I want this for easy comparison later on.

My log file has the format:

```
2012-11-06 10:32:45
<log message follows here on multiple lines in XML format>
```

I am using the following gawk expression to convert my date/time to a timestamp:

```
$ gawk '/^([0-9]{2,4}-?){3} ([0-9]{2}\:?){3}/{print $0;gsub(/\:/," ");print mktime($0)}' logfile.txt
```

Output will be:

```
2012-11-01 15:27:28
1293719248
```

This is actually what I am looking for but the question is if the regexp is correct? Since I am far from a regexp master I would like too know if this is ok or not. Could this be done in a fancier way when it comes to the regexp? The format used in the log file will never change there for I did not bother to make a universal date/time match. Maybe something else in my expression is fubar? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you only work on your log file, the regex is ok. Because you could assume that your log file will always give a valid Datetime String. (e.g. `2012-13-56 28:23:77` won't happen)

But what I am gonna point out is, your awk  codes may have problem.

- I don't know which gawk version are you using (I guess > 4.0),  `--re-interval` option is not default if version < 4.
- There is an error in your string replace: you should replace "-" to " " as well right?

awk man page:

```
 mktime(datespec)
                 Turns datespec into a time stamp of the same form as returned by systime().  The datespec is a string of the form YYYY MM DD HH  MM  SS[  DST].
```

see the difference:

```
kent$  gawk '{print $0;gsub(/:|-/," ");print mktime($0)}' <<<"2012-11-01 15:27:28"
2012-11-01 15:27:28
1351780048

output with your awk line:
2012-11-01 15:27:28
1293719248
```

Comment: Yes, I use 4.0.1. Aha, good point (and interesting)! Since my input generated a timestamp and not -1 I figured it swallowed the date part including the - correctly. I read the man page but was lazy and dumb and ignored the - based on the previous statement. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The ERE to match:

```
2012-11-06 10:32:45
```

on a line of it's own is:

```
^[[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){2} [[:digit:]]{2}(:[[:digit:]]{2}){2}$
```

but you could probably get away with:

```
^[[:digit:]]([[:digit:]: -][[:digit:]]{2}){6}$
```

without getting any false matches.

Comment: +1 - this is entirely correct.  Note that most regex implementations let you use `\d` as short-hand for `[:digit:]`.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* possibly do away with regex altogether and simply test for `mktime()`'s failure. Obviously this depends on whether or not your data could contain lines that have a date/time look about them. However, you may not have considered doing something like this:

```
awk '{ line = $0; gsub(/[:-]/, " "); time = mktime($0) } time != "-1" { print line ORS time }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
2012-11-06 10:32:45
1352161965
```

From the man page:

```
If datespec does not contain enough elements or if the resulting time is out of 
range, mktime() returns −1.
```

Comment: This is quite clever, I will +1 this because it show a different way to approach the problem. Out of curiosity would the performance impact be bigger by doing this?

Comment: @Qben: In my testing this is actually faster than the regex method you describe (even when I consider Kent's answer and reduce your two print statements to just one). This method still takes only two thirds the time that yours does. Interesting hey.

Comment: That is interesting indeed. I guess the people who wrote mktime() have a better/more optimized regexp than I have. :-)